# Why is my neural network not improving?

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, regression, keras

I am struggling to understand why i am getting such a high loss/val_loss rate on my training. I am training a regression network. I've normalized the input data to range between -1 to 1, and left the output data unaltered, its range is approx. between  -100 to 100.

I chose to normalize the input such that i could use tanh, as activation function as it outputs within this range.

[image]

[image]

The neural network consist of 3 layers.

```
  print "Model definition!"
    model = Sequential()

    #act = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=400,input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    #act1 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=400,input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    #act2 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=400, input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    act4=ELU(100)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=13, input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=act4))
```

The mapping between the input and output consist of mapping audio samples into MFCC features.  The samples are the ones i've normalized to the described range.

why am i getting these results?

what could/should i improve/change ?

cv code running:

```
#Each frame length = 118
#Each feature length = 13
############################### Training setup ##################################

#Define 10 folds:
seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False, random_state=None)
print "Splits"
cvscores_acc = []
cvscores_loss = []
hist = []
i = 0
for train, test in kfold.split(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized):

    print "Model definition!"
    model = Sequential()

    #act = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=400,input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    #act1 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=400,input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    #act2 = PReLU(init='normal', weights=None)
    #model.add(Dense(output_dim=400, input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=K.tanh))

    act4=ELU(100)
    model.add(Dense(output_dim=13, input_dim=400, init="normal",activation=act4))

    print "Compiling"
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='RMSprop')
    print "Compile done! "

    print '\n'

    print "Train start"

    reduce_lr=ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1, mode='auto', epsilon=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0.00000001)

    log=csv_logger = CSVLogger('training_'+str(i)+'.csv')


    hist_current = model.fit(train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[test],train_set_output_vstacked[test], shuffle=False,validation_split=0.1 ,  nb_epoch=1000,verbose=1,callbacks=[reduce_lr,log])

    hist.append(hist_current)

    loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x=train_set_data_vstacked_normalized[train],y=train_set_output_vstacked[train],verbose=1)
    print
    print('loss: ', loss)
    print('accuracy: ', accuracy)
    print()
    print model.summary()
    print "New Model:"
    cvscores_acc.append(accuracy)
    cvscores_loss.append(loss)
    print "Model stored"
    model.save("Model"+str(i))
    i=i+1

print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores_acc), numpy.std(cvscores_acc)))
print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores_loss), numpy.std(cvscores_loss)))
```

Comment: That's classical overfitting, right? Have you tried reducing the number of hidden dimensions?